# Why is SpriteKit loading all device sizes (~ipad and @2x~ipad) textures into memory?

Tags: ios, memory, sprite-kit, texture-atlas, sktextureatlas

I'm loading textures into SpriteKit for use in an animation using the following code -

```
NSMutableArray *animFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
SKTextureAtlas *animTextureAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed: @"bearAnimation"];

for (int i = 1; i < animTextureAtlas.textureNames.count / 3; i++) {
    NSString *texture = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%04d", i];
    [animFrames addObject:[animTextureAtlas textureNamed:texture]];
}

// This is a strong property of an NSArray where I store frames of animation
self.bearAnimationFrames = animFrames;

static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    [SKTexture preloadTextures:self.bearAnimationFrames withCompletionHandler:^{}];
});
```

My issue is that using the above code on an atlas that contains three versions of each image for retina iPad, non-retina iPad and retina iPhone results in the app using memory for all of them. Not just the ones it needs.

How can I make it so that the only textures loaded into memory are the ones the device the app is running on needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I read Noah Witherspoon's answer "***Set up separate atlases, one for each type of screen.***"

Next, I see that you still had more questions "***Anyway how do I go about accessing an atlas based on the category of device used? Should I just be checking for an iPad or iPhone and then breaking down the iPad section into are you an iPad 2?***"

I think that Noah was trying to point out that instead of creating 1 big atlas that contains all images for 3 different versions of screen resolutions, your code should probably create 3 separate atlases (with 3 separate names) : one of each version of the screen resolution.

If you go with his approach, then in your code, during the initialization phase of or your app, perhaps, you could check for the device (or ***the screen resolution***), and then your code can first create only 1 proper atlas for that one particular screen resolution, and after that you code can load that atlas onto RAM. This way, your app only creates and loads 1 set of images for 1 particular device onto RAM instead of loading all 3 sets of images onto RAM.

So, if you go with this strategy, you can save a large amount of RAM that your app uses at runtime. This is very important and valuable. I have seen many apps crash after running for awhile on the iPad because they use too much RAM, especially in iOS 9.0 and newer.

---

If you have a better solution, please share with us.

I am a new game developer, and am still trying to learn a lot of new techniques to improve my game. So, I would greatly appreciate new tips or lessons on this forum...

Comment: In the end we actually had to move away from using the animation we wanted to use on the iPad 2. The textures were just too large and the animation was ultimately laggy. We opted instead for a smaller simpler animation when the device was an iPad 2.

Comment: Additionally given App Thinning this is also less of an issue than it once was. At least in theory. I'm also not working on games anymore so I can't say for sure. I would be focusing on iOS 10 and later just the leave out the iPad 2 as soon as possible if I were creating anything new for release later this year.

Comment: Thanks for you advice on testing on iPad2. I am developing and testing my game on my real device iPad 3, and it works well. But, I don't have a real device for iPad1 and iPad2 to test my game, and I am afraid I may run into the "animation lagging" issue. So, is there a way for me to tell Apple that I only want release my game for the third and newer generation of iPad ? Or does Apple force developers to make sure that the games must work for all types of iPad (including iPad1 and iPad2) before they can release the game ? Thanks.

Comment: Updated:  I have just understood what you meant in your previous suggestion for me.  Some people are telling me that iOS 10 will be released soon, and probably iPad 2 won't be able to run iOS 10. So, if I set the release requirement for my game such that it only supports iOS 10 and newer versions, then I may be able to skip the support for iPad 1 and iPad 2.  Thanks.

Comment: Apple have announced that iOS 10 will not support the iPad 2, but also it will not support the iPad 3 as that device was seriously underpowered and was only in the market for a matter of months before it was replaced by the iPad 4. If your only device is an iPad 3 then that might be a problem for you with development. Unfortunately there isn't any other way to exclude iPad 2 devices. If you support only devices from iOS 6 and later then iPad 1 will not be able to run your app. The lowest I would go is iOS 8.1. If you're using SpriteKit there are bug fixes in 8.1 that are worth not using 8.0.

Comment: Fortunately, I've just found out my iPad is actually iPad 4.  :-)   So, I can exclude iPad 3 and the older ones by setting the iOS to iOS 10 when submitting my game to the App Store.   Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Set up separate atlases, one for each type of screen. There’s no SpriteKit API for “load this texture but only some bits of it”.

Comment: Thanks. I know that the atlas is converted into sprite sheets ending in @2x and such which is why I figure it loads the correct images, but I still don't see why it can see all of those in an atlas when it's split into different sprite sheets behind the scenes already.

Comment: Anyway how do I go about accessing an atlas based on the category of device used? Should I just be checking for an iPad or iPhone and then breaking down the iPad section into are you an iPad 2?